# how to show fragment from custom alertdialog, alert dialog is in adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am trying to show fragment from a custom alertdilog's button click event, alert dialog is in fragment's adapter, i wanted to show fragment from alertdialog button click but i am unable to do so.

alertdialog code:

```
    holder.commentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        final AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();

                        View viewTmp_comment=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.comment_show_layout,null,false);
                        RecyclerView recyclerView_commentShow=(RecyclerView)viewTmp_comment.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId_commentShow);
                        TextView textViewId_commentShow_layout=(TextView)viewTmp_comment.findViewById(R.id.textViewId_commentShow_layout);
                        ImageButton commentSendButtonId_Post=(ImageButton)viewTmp_comment.findViewById(R.id.commentSendButtonId_Post);
                        ImageButton imageUpload_CommentButton=(ImageButton)viewTmp_comment.findViewById(R.id.imageUploadButtonId_comment);
                        ImageButton smileyUpload_CommentButton=(ImageButton)viewTmp_comment.findViewById(R.id.smileyButtonId_comment);
                        editTextId_CommentPost=(EditText) viewTmp_comment.findViewById(R.id.editTextId_CommentPost);
    //                RelativeLayout smileyLoadLayoutId_CommentAdapter=(RelativeLayout)

                        final CommentShowAdapter commentShowAdapter=new CommentShowAdapter(context,newsFeedClassArrayList.get(position).getCommentShowClassArrayList(),"NewsFeed");
                        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                        recyclerView_commentShow.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                        if(newsFeedClassArrayList.get(position).getCommentShowClassArrayList()!=null) {
                            recyclerView_commentShow.setAdapter(commentShowAdapter);

                            DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(context, linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
                            recyclerView_commentShow.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
                            commentShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            recyclerView_commentShow.onChildDetachedFromWindow(null);
                        }else {
                            builder.setMessage("No comments yet");
                        }

                    //comment show alert dismiss
                    textViewId_commentShow_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            try {
                                if(alertDialog.isShowing()){
                                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }catch (Exception e){}
                        }
                    });


**//here i am trying to lauch fragment**
                    smileyUpload_CommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            ServiceClass.setSmileyKey("comment");

                            smileyFragment=new SmileyShowFragment();

                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.smileyLoadLayoutId_CommentAdapter);

                            if (!(fragment instanceof SmileyShowFragment)) {

                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.smileyLoadLayoutId_CommentAdapter, smileyFragment, "Smiley").commit();
                            } else {

                                fragmentTransaction.remove(smileyFragment).commit();

                            }
                        }
                    });

                        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                        Window window = alertDialog.getWindow(); lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
                        lp.width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        lp.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM; window.setAttributes(lp);

                        alertDialog.setView(viewTmp_comment);
                        alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

alert xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ddd"

    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewId_commentShow_layout"
        android:text="Comments"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/underline"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId_commentShow"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:background="#1470a6"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/camera"
            android:id="@+id/imageUploadButtonId_comment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/smileyButtonId_comment"
            android:src="@drawable/smiley"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextId_CommentPost"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:hint="Your comment"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/commentSendButtonId_Post"
            android:src="@drawable/send_comment"
            android:background="#1470a6"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/smileyLoadLayoutId_CommentAdapter"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

how to solve this problem? is it possible to show fragment inside alertdialog.i have searched on google but no similar solution

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate customized dialog. To do so you can extend DialogFragment and on onCreateDialog() set up your views and proper assignments.  Create a layout for your customized dialog fragment class with a fragment inside.  You can create an interface on your customized dialog to listen for actions like button clicks or others.  Then, onClick of your button use fragment manager to show the fragment within your dialogfragment.  Something like below:

> //Give it a fragment with a FrameLayout to hold the fragment if you
>   need to hold more than one or with just add a fragment in your layout
>   if you do not need a holder.

```
public class MyCustomizedDialog extends DialogFragment{

private TextView dialogTitle;
private TextView dialogText;
private FrameLayout myFragmentContainer;
private Button myButton;
private CustomDialogListener customDialogListener;

public interface CustomDialogListener{
  //set listeners here, i.e. for buttons clicked by user
  public void onBtnClick();
}

public setDialogFragmentListener(CustomDialogListener customDialogListener){
    this.customDialogListener = customDialogListener;
}
@override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  //initialize dialog
  setUpMyCustomDialog(dialog);
  return dialog;
}

public void setUpMyCustomDialog(Dialog dialog){
    dialogTitle = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title_tv);
    dialogText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text_tv);
    myFragmentContainer=(FrameLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.child_fragment_container);
    myButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.myButton);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //initialize your fragment here.
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: my alertdialog is customized